# Conformal cyclic cosmology, black hole and Weyl curvature

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, curvature, conformal-field-theory

Roger penrose in his theory "conformal cyclic cosmology" states that after a google there would be a giant black hole. Does black hole have Weyl curvature? If it does, then we know that curvature creates particle, right? So will there be enough particles  out of curvature that could probably create other large scale structures?

Comment: How can a new big bang emerge from the future black holes?