# Conformal Cyclic Cosmology

Tags: cosmology, entropy, space-expansion, conformal-field-theory

In this conformal cyclic cosmology, where did the very first eon come from? How did the very first eon start with possible lowest entropy?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/709089/2451

Comment: As there is no "first aeon", the question (as it's currently stated) is unanswerable.  Conformal cyclic cosmology is past- and future-eternal.

Comment: At https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhbULagUKhA , there's a video that might provide a clearer picture of how it works, and of how it differs from the inflationary model (which, incidentally, also has a past- and future-eternal version, in Aguirre & Gratton's "Steady-state eternal inflation").

Comment: In understanding why we might understand the future better than the past, I think it's helpful to remember that we're biological creatures:  Predicting the future helps us in our survival (which involves competition or conflict with other terrestrial creatures), whereas understanding the past is interesting, but much more apt to be irrelevant.